# Out of memory with conv3d (TensorFlow)

Tags: tensorflow

Please consider this very simple minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 8

a = np.random.rand(batch_size, 5, 2048, 2048, 1)
b = np.random.rand(5, 8, 8, 1, 1)

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    at = tf.placeholder(shape=a.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
    bt = tf.placeholder(shape=b.shape, dtype=tf.float32)

    ct = tf.nn.conv3d(at, bt, strides=[1, 5, 8, 8, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(ct, feed_dict={at: a.astype(np.float32), bt: b.astype(np.float32)})
```

I have a batch `a` of tensors with shape `(5x2048x2048)` and a kernel `b` with shape `(5x8x8)`. By performing convolution with strides of `[5, 8, 8]`, the shape of the resulting tensor will be `(1, 256, 256)`. I'm feeding data using placeholders to simulate a real-world use case where data is fed from the outside.

When I run the code above on a GTX960 with 2GB of memory, I get the following error:

```
Ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.2KiB. See logs for memory state.
```

How is it possible that TensorFlow cannot allocate such a little amount of memory? Can this be a bug in TensorFlow? The error disappears if I use a smaller `batch_size`, but I am wondering what is going on here, since in principle the whole problem should fit entirely in GPU memory (indeed the problem size is only 640.00MiB).

The log says:

```
Bin for 1.2KiB was 1.0KiB, Chunk State: 
Chunk at 0x703d40000 of size 1280
Chunk at 0x703d40500 of size 671088640
Chunk at 0x72bd40500 of size 1280
Chunk at 0x72bd40a00 of size 2097152
Chunk at 0x72bf40a00 of size 1168111104
     Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 2.5KiB
1 Chunks of size 2097152 totalling 2.00MiB
1 Chunks of size 671088640 totalling 640.00MiB
1 Chunks of size 1168111104 totalling 1.09GiB
Sum Total of in-use chunks: 1.71GiB
```

I have identified the different chunks as follows:

- the chunk sized `1280` is the kernel `b`: 5 * 8 * 8 * 4 = 1280, where 4 is the size of a `float32`
- the chunk sized `2097152` (2.00MiB) is the convolution output: 8 * 1 * 256 * 256 * 4 = 2097152, where 8 is the `batch_size` and 4 is again the size of a `float32`
- the chunk sized `671088640` (640.00MiB) is the input `a`: 8 * 5 * 2048 * 2048 * 4 =  671088640
- the chunk sized `1168111104` (more than 1GiB) is the remainder amount of GPU memory, that TensorFlow allocates by default. As a matter of fact, if I change the problem size (i.e. `batch_size`) the size of this chunk varies accordingly so that all chunks always sum up to 1.71GiB on my system.

If I understand things correctly, there should be plenty of memory still available. So I can't figure out why I get the out of memory error. Am I missing something, or can this be a bug? I'd appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this. Thanks!

P.S. Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`. There are no processes taking up GPU memory.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   54C    P0    26W / 160W |      0MiB /  1996MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you using this card also for the main desktop or is only dedicated to computing?

Comment: I ran your problem on my GPU, it actually passed through. My GPU has 12G memory but I only use 0.167 of it.

Comment: @fabrizioM i use the card just for computing, not for the main desktop

Comment: @Fake I also happen to have a Tesla K40 with 12GB of memory on a different machine. I tried as you did (I guess using `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.167`) but I still get the out of memory issue

Comment: No one found an answer to this? having the same problem and I got 8 GB on my gpu.

Comment: It sounds like tensorflow-gpu is not properly set up, so tensorflow is only using CPUs. Do you get messages like "successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally" at the beginning of your run?

Comment: @HillarySanders yes, I do. That doesn't seem to be a misconfiguration problem, at least in my case I am sure TensorFlow is using the GPU indeed.